# How do I update a nested property with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I've got a ToDo class which has properties for Staff and Priority. If a user updates a ToDo item, changes the TaskName and maybe sets a new Priority how do I update the Priority property -

```
public class ToDo : BaseEntity
{
    public DateTime? DueDate { get; set; }
    public String Notes { get; set; }
    public virtual Priority Priority { get; set; }
    public virtual Staff Staff { get; set; }
    public String TaskName { get; set; }
}
```

In my WinForms code I have the following save method:

```
private void Save()    
{    
    var todo = new ToDo    
    {    
        ID = ToDoID,    
        Staff = ddlStaff.SelectedValue,    
        Priority = ddlPriority.SelectedValue,    
        TaskName = txtTaskName.Text.Trim(),
        Notes = txtNotes.Text.Trim(),
        DueDate = String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtDueDate.Text) ? DateTime.Now : DateTime.Parse(txtDueDate.Text.ToString())
};

 _todoController.SaveOrUpdate(todo);
```

}

The UI has drop down / combo lists for Staff and Priority, but ddlPriority.SelectedValue isn't a Priority object. I *could* call the database passing the SelectedValue to return the Priority object and then pass that into the ToDo object but that seems crazy just to create/maintain the relationship between the ToDo item and it's priority.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also instead have an extra property called `PriorityId` that you set and get. This is a very common scenario in web apps since they're stateless.

**EDIT:** You can also do something like this:

```
var selectedStaff = new Staff();
selectedStaff.Id = 2;
context.Staff.Attach(selectedStaff); // The important part.

var todo = new ToDo    
{    
    ID = ToDoID,    
    Staff = selectedStaff,
    Priority = ddlPriority.SelectedValue,    
    TaskName = txtTaskName.Text.Trim(),
    Notes = txtNotes.Text.Trim(),
    ....
}

context.SaveChanges();
```

Calling `context.Staff.Attach(someStaffObject)` basically adds the staff object to the context to allow it to be referenced. You have to be sure that you *set the key* property before calling `Attach()`.

Comment: Typically I use the fk (PriorityID) approach, but all the examples seem to just have the entity referenced rather than Id and I wanted to see how that worked out for me. Being able to query against the entity is a nice benefit - but a round trip to the database just to update the ToDo concerns me. I've also got a Staff relationship so that's going to be another trip and this is a 'simple' object with only 2 relationships, what about those that are more complex?

Comment: @Simon - Most examples have the reference approach because they're examples. They're not tailored for real world scenarios. A more "complex" object would still use the PK/FK approach I described above. See my edit above for another way (which might be what you're trying to do).